# Grails 3 set remote debug ip:port

Tags: debugging, grails, grails-3.0

I would like to remotely debug grails 3 application. However I didn't found how can I change implicit debugger port. Is there a way to do something like `grails run-app --jvm-debug --debugger-port=9999 --debugger-addr=10.0.50.55`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle and modify the 5005 by the port that you want:

```
bootRun {
    addResources = false // We can set it to true if we would like to reload src/main/resources
    jvmArgs = ["-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run your grails application by directly starting the [`Application`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#applicationClass) class located in `grails-app/init`. It has a `static void main` and be run as a regular application. You can run it from you IDE with a debug profile of your choice.